# Send a value via EmailJs without using a form

Tags: reactjs

I want to send an EmailJs with two parameters, the email that comes from the form, and the let toysList, that comes from the localStorage(and converted into a string via .toString()). How can I do that? I know how to connect the email because is in the form, but I don't know where i should put the toysList that is a variable.

```
import React from "react";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";

let toysList = window.JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")).toString();

function ClientSubmit() {

    function sendEmail(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        emailjs
          .sendForm(
            "...",
            "...",
            e.target,
            "..."
          )
          .then(
            (result) => {
              console.log(result.text);
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error.text);
            }
          );
        e.target.reset();
        alert(
          "Email send successfully!"
        );
      }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Give us your mail and we will give you the price of the items</h3>
      <form onSubmit={sendEmail}>
        <div className="col-4">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            className="form-control"
            name="email"
            placeholder="email@example.com"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3 col-2 ">
          <input
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            value="Send"
          ></input>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a hidden  in the form containing the value of the toyList so when you submit the form the toyList will be there.

```
<form onSubmit={sendEmail}>
    <div className="col-4">
      <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        className="form-control"
        name="email"
        placeholder="email@example.com"
      />
      <input
        type="hidden"
        className="form-control"
        name="toyList"
        defaultValue={toyList}
      />
    </div>
    <div className="mb-3 col-2 ">
      <input
        type="submit"
        className="btn btn-primary"
        value="Send"
      ></input>
    </div>
  </form>
```